# Application (Not a Markup Language) for Producing a User Manual

Tags: pdf, documentation, publishing, manuals

Can anyone recommend a program to create user manuals with?  Not a markup language (like LaTeX or DocBook) but more something interactive like Scribus.  As I'm not the only one that will update the manual the software should be something that's easy for a novice to pick up but still has some advanced features (like linking in text from external sources/tables, handling masterpages/themes etc.).

Regards,
Oscar

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Technical Publishing Software - Views on [FrameMaker](http://www.adobe.com/products/framemaker.html) and Its Alternatives**

I've done spec documents with LaTeX and Framemaker, and designed a Framemaker workflow to support a team of 5 analysts producing a spec document for an insurance underwriting system.  The document was expected to get to 2,000 pages or so.  Many years ago (around 1992-1993) I also worked briefly as a typesetter.

Framemaker is designed for technical documentation and does it **very well indeed.**  It also has features designed to support very large documents with multiple authors - people use this system to do documents with more than 100,000 pages.  It is also more accessible  than LaTeX to users familiar with word processing software.

**Key features of Framemaker:**

- **Documents consisting of multiple
  files:** You can pull together a
  'Book' with multiple subsections in
  different files.  The document can
  also be kept in source control.
- **Textual MIF format for
  import/export:** The importer is
  somewhat finicky (I found generating
  working LaTeX to be easier) but you can
  generate items such as data
  dictionaries and import them into
  the document.  The file has textual
  anchors (see below) so you can
  create cross-reference links that
  will be stable across imports.  I
  find this to be a key feature for
  specs as it allows cross-references
  to link directly to generated items.
- **Powerful tagging, indexing and cross-referencing System:** Everything
  is based on tags in Framemaker and
  it is easy to apply tags quickly. 
  This means that cross-referencing,
  indexing, conditional text and
  applying styles en-masse is easy and
  *just works*.  You can generate indexes and TOCs based on tags, so
  having multiple specialised indexes
  (such as a list of data field names
  from screens or a data dictionary)
  is easy to do.  The document I
  described above had 4 separate
  indexes.
- **Stable:** Framemaker is designed for
  professionals so it doesn't second
  guess you in the way that word does.
  It is also much more stable on large
  documents.  Anyone who's tried to
  write a document of more than 50-100
  pages on Word should have a pretty
  fair idea of what this implies.
- **Scriptable:** FM has a C API and there
  are various scripting plugins
  ([FrameScript](http://www.framescript.com/) and [FMPython](http://www.framemakerfdksource.com/bloggers/windows/2007/02/17/fmpython-download-here/)
  being probably the most widely used)
  which can be used to automate jobs
  in FM.  [Framemaker 10](http://www.adobe.com/products/framemaker.html) adds support 
  for a Javascript based scripting tool 
  called [Extendscript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/framemaker/using/WSd5e89bb44d752f2f4e0f6b6612c81bacb1a-7ff4.html), presumably
  ported across from the scripting facility
  in InDesign.
- **Single-sourcing:** From a single FM
  document you can produce PDF,
  Windows Help (CHM), HTML and print
  documents fairly easily.  The
  cross-references also resolve to
  hyperlinks.
- **Global style controls:** You can
  easily set up styles for a document
  and apply it across the whole
  document.  It also facilitates
  running headers and footers with a
  great deal of flexibility in having
  them track sections, versions,
  chapters etc.

**Alternatives to Framemaker**

- **LaTeX/Lout:** You've already indicated
  that you don't want a markup
  lanaguage, but the [TeX](http://www.ctan.org) and
  [Lout](http://lout.wiki.sourceforge.net/) systems are used for large
  structured documents and do this
  well.
- **[Ventura Publisher:](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/us/en/Product/1152105061811#tabview=tab0)** Probably the
  only real alternative to Framemaker 
  if you want that sort of user interface
  without paying bodily parts for the
  privilege.
  It has strong support for structured
  documents and an XML-based document
  interchange format.  It's now owned
  by Corel, who still appear to be actively promoting it.

  There are a couple of other technical publishing tools on the market: [Quicksilver](http://www.broadvision.com/bvsn/bvcom/ep/programView.do?pageTypeId=8155&programPage=%2Fjsp%2Fwww%2Fcontent%2FgeneralContentBody.jsp&programId=8297&channelId=-9482&BV_SessionID=NNNN1185750526.1229445772NNNN&BV_EngineID=ccccadeejdjfiegcefecefedgfhdfng.0)  (which used to be known as [Interleaf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaf)) and [ArborText](http://www.ptc.com/products/arbortext/).  These two are powerful tools  - Interleaf used to be the market leader in this field at one point - but quite expensive.
- **[Adobe Indesign:](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign/)** Although Adobe
  claim you can do large documents
  with InDesign, the cross-referencing
  and other large document features
  tend to be viewed as lacking by
  Framemaker afficionados.  There is,
  however, a text entry system for it
  called [InCopy](http://www.adobe.com/products/incopy/) that apparently
  does have this sort of
  functionality and quite
  a large body of [Third-party
  plugins](http://www.adobe.com/products/plugins/indesign/), some of which do
  support tagging and other such facilities.
  InDesign also has a scripting API and
  a JavaScript interpreter for executing
  scripts.

  I haven't used Indesign,
  so I can't really comment on how
  well it works in practice.
- **[DocBook:](http://www.docbook.org/)**  This is really just
  a standard format for structured
  documents but has a large ecosystem
  of tools surrounding it for writing
  and rendering documents.  If you
  don't want to use LaTeX you will
  probably not want to use DocBook for
  similar reasons.  As [Vinko Vrsalovic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371654/application-not-a-markup-language-for-producing-a-user-manual#371674)
  points out (+1), [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182334/company-insists-on-using-a-binary-format-for-all-our-documentation#182591) goes to a StackOverflow
  post from someone describing using
  DocBook in practice.
  I've never really used DocBook and I've
  made so many edits to this post that it's now in Wiki mode, so 
  someone familiar with DocBook might 
  want to elaborate on this.
- **Word processing software:** [Word](http://www.microsoft.com/office/2007-rlt/en-GB/Default.aspx?s=whatsnew&id=word&WT.mc_id=ad&WT.srch=1)
  has serious shortcomings as a
  technical publishing tool and is not
  recommended.  [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) has
  somewhat better structured
  documentation functionality than
  word and may be a better choice if
  politics or requirement to use .doc
  as a document interchange format
  preclude a better alternative. 
  [Wordperfect](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/gb/en/Product/1207676528492?trkid=ukgoogwpoq406#tabview=tab0) is also
  considerably better for
  documentation-in-the-large than word
  and still has a presence in several vertical markets
  such as legal offices.
- **[Madcap Software's](http://www.madcapsoftware.com/) [Blaze](http://www.madcapsoftware.com/products/blaze/) and [Flare](http://www.madcapsoftware.com/products/flare/):** These
  are new kids on the block and live
  in roughly the same space as
  Framemaker.  The company was founded by former
  eHelp (creators of RoboHelp) employees and is
  actively developing, with multiple releases yearly. Their
  offerings have greatly expanded in the past two years,
  to the detriment of the quality of the individual products.
  It seems focus has been on turning out new products and
  by consequence there are a lot of "fit and finish" issues in
  each. The authors have chosen to reinvent the wheel in many ways, 
  resulting in confusing and often broken implementations. Save often, 
  you will encounter unhandled exceptions. Source control integration
  is flaky. For example, moving or deleting a group of files will result in
  one source control commit for each file deletion. Big PITA when
  you have source control email notifications. Hello 500 emails.
  Flare can import Word and Framemaker files, but the import
  is far from seamless. Expect to retain all of your content
  but plan on completely re-styling from scratch. 
  Flare shares many of Word's tendancies to do too much behind
  the scenes and assume what the user would choose. The HTML looks
  like what Word outputs when you export HTML - lots of custom tags
  and attributes, deeply nested inline styles, etc. The text
  editor is maddening, for example, its cursor model is different
  than any other software you've ever used.

**Framemaker vs. LaTeX**

These two are main systems I have used to produce large, presentable system documents and I've had good results with both.

- **Ease of Learning:** TeX can give you absolute control but actually
  achieving this on a complex LaTeX
  document without breaking other
  items isn't trivial, particularly
  where a large number of macro
  packages are involved.  Basic LaTeX
  isn't hard to learn, but making
  modified versions of .sty files that
  still work takes a bit of tinkering
  if you're not a really deep TeX
  hacker.  It can be done but be
  prepared to spend quite a lot of
  time fiddling.

  Framemaker can give you a good degree of control on the look of the document and isn't that hard to learn.  Getting a house style and tweaking the layout (which you probably will have to do) will be easier with Framemaker.
- **Ease of Text Entry:** You can use tools such as [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) to provide a
  wordprocessor-like front end to
  LaTeX, and these work well if you
  want to write large bodies of text. 
  Framemaker's DTP-like user interface
  works in a way familiar to people
  who are used to wordproessing
  software.  From this perspective
  there is little practical
  difference.
- **Templating Document Structure:** Framemaker allows a document
  structure to be defined in terms of
  tags or an XML schema (if using
  Structured Framemaker).  LaTeX has a
  set of canned structural elements
  that are flexible enough to be
  useful.  Adding additional
  structural elements (e.g. a data
  dictionary item) can be done as a
  macro, but making them auto-number
  is a bit more challenging and you will
  need to poke around behind the
  scenes.  Both can do it, but it's
  considerably more technical to do it
  in LaTeX in anything but trivial
  cases.

  Also, LaTeX does not have
  the facility to template the
  document structure in the way that
  Structured Framemaker does. 
  However, you can achieve this type
  of effect with DocBook and then
  generate to LaTeX if desired.
- **Ease of Integration:** I found making a generator for non-trivially
  complex MIF files to be quite
  fiddly.  The MIF parser is quite
  pernickety in FM and doesn't really
  give good diagnostics.  LaTeX
  produces far better error messages
  and is quite a bit less fussy.

**Technical Publishing Software vs. Layout Software**

Page layout software started with [Pagemaker](http://www.adobe.com/products/pagemaker/) and the other main players in this space were its competitor [Quark Xpess](http://8.quark.com/) and now InDesign, with which Adobe is essentially trying to deprecate and replace it and Framemaker.  [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/), which you mentioned before, lives in the same space as these products.

If you are producing a manual with less than (say) 50-100 pages, one of the packages would probably do an adequate job.  They are really designed for advertising and layout-heavy publication tasks such as magazines, so their support for large-document features of the sort found in Framemaker is fairly limited.  The key issue with these products is scalability - they do not work well on large documents.

Just for reference I have actually typeset a 200-page book (someone's autobiography) using Pagemaker.  While the fine-grained kerning and leading control helps a bit for copyfitting, it is still a highly manual process to lay out a book sized document.  In this case the book was just straight text with no significant cross-referencing or structure other than chapters.  Doing a complex technical spec document or manual this size with Pagemaker would have been very fiddly and probably next to impossible to get right without any mistakes.

**Technical Publishing vs. Word Processing Software**

This is more of a description of key shortcomings of MS-Word for large spec documents.  However, it will illustrate some of the main features required for documentation-in-the-large:

- **Indexing and Cross-Referencing:** This is a real chore in Word, and
  quite unstable.  Framemaker's
  tagging features and LaTeX's labels
  mean that you can assign a tag or
  known label (in a predictable format
  if necessary).  The textual format
  for the tag anchors is exposed in
  the user interface, and is used for
  the linkage.  In Word, the anchors
  are much more opaque and not
  easily controllable in this way. 
  Combined with the clumsy user
  interface and instability of the
  product, this makes maintaining
  these fiddly, and often unstable -
  you often have to manually fix them
  up.
- **Templated Layouts:** Style support in word are quite basic and
  numbering tends to be somewhat
  unstable.  FrameMaker is all about
  driving from the tags and applying
  styles based on the tags.  Global
  style changes just work in
  Framemaker in a way that they do not
  in Word.
- **Large multi-file Documents:** I've never been able to make this work
  well in Word, but it is a key
  feature in Framemaker and LaTeX. 
  Again, Word's instability means that
  you tend to spend a lot of time
  tidying up after it.  As the
  document grows larger, the
  proportion of time spent on this
  work grows quadratically -
  propensity for breakage proportional
  to *n* (size of document) * time to
  fix proportional to size *n* (time
  to fix)
- **Why is Word so Unstable:** Word does a lot behind the scenes to
  support novice users and intervene
  in layouts.  It is also not really
  frame-based (text flow conceptually
  separate from document layout), but
  the developers try to implement
  various frame-like behaviours in the UI.  When
  the A.I. second-guesses you on a
  complex document it often does the
  wrong thing.  Framemaker 'treats the
  user as an adult' and does none of
  this so things stay where you put
  them.

  Other word processors such as
  Open Office and WordPerfect do not
  misbehave in quite the same way as
  Word, which is one of the reasons
  that ***just about any*** word
  processor other than Word will do a
  better job of technical documents.
- **Pre-Flighting:** In documentation-speak, this is the
  process of checking that your
  assemblage of files for the document
  (image files etc.) is correct before
  committing to print.  The
  professional systems will complain
  about things that are wrong, giving
  you a chance to correct it.  Word
  will just put on a happy face and
  try to fix things behind the scenes.

  A good example of this is a word
  file with linked graphics.  If you
  copy the file and graphics to
  another directory and update one of
  the graphics in situ, word may well
  still read the file from the old
  path (I've seen it do this) and not
  the new one you've just updated.
  However, this behaviour is not consistent and
  typifies the rampant abuse of
  unstable heuristics in that product.
- **Pre-Press Support:** A publishing system extends into the pre-press
  phase of the workflow.  This means
  it covers preparation for print. 
  Word processing software tends not
  to have this functionality or have
  it in a very limited form.

Without getting too far into this, a key difference is that publishing software tends to treat you like a consenting adult and not get in the way when you want to scale or automate things.  One *can* use word processing software for large scale documentation but it has many design decisions adapted to casual users writing short documents with little regard for quality.  These adaptations come at the expense of fitness-for-task on large scale document preparation work.  The main issues I find with Word for spec documents are the poor indexing and cross-referencing and general instability issues where I am always having to go back and fix things.  However, political considerations in most environments (I'm a contractor) mean one is often stuck with it.

**Some general comments on the state of technical documentation software**

Framemaker would be the obvious choice if Adobe didn't keep giving off signals that they are trying to deprecate it and move its user base to InDesign.  However, FM is widely used in aerospace, software and engineering circles and Adobe's management would face a [lynch mob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynch_mob) if they actually EOL'd the product without a credible migration path.  From what one reads on the web, Adobe's acquisition of FM was driven by John Warnock, but he was ousted and FM became a victim of office politics.  The net result is that it's been moved to maintenance mode and is quite stagnant.

Ventura Publisher has also been relegated to a niche market to some extent, but at least Corel do not have two competing product lines in the way that Adobe do.  It is probably a passable substitute for FM and may be more politically acceptable to PHB types as it is marketed as a 'business publishing' system.

Quicksilver and Arbortext both seem to be viable products, but are very expensive.  I've not used either, so I can't really make any real judgement on their merits.

The markup language systems are free and very powerful in many ways.  Lout might be a bit easier to work with as it doesn't have quite the level of legacy baggage that LaTeX does.    DocBook is also quite widely used and does have quite a bit of tool support.  These technologies put a significant squeeze on the 'geek' end of Framemaker's market share *and do so on their merits* - they have probably taken quite a chunk out of Adobe's profit margins over the years.  I would not dismiss these technologies out of hand, but they will be harder to learn in practice.

You might try evaluating InDesign and a selected set of plugins (concentrate on those for tagging and cross-ref/index management).  Finally, some of the word processing software (Wordperfect and OpenOffice) give you a reasonable toolkit for structured documentation and work considerably better for this than MS-Word.

**PostScript**

Yes, that is a pun.  I haven't touched on Pre-Press functionality of any of these products.  Printing and Pre-Press are technical fields in their own right and the scope for expensive mistakes means you should probably leave this up to specialists.
Framemaker, InDesign, Ventura, QuickSilver, Arbortext and (presumably) the MadCap products all come with facilities to do pre-press preparation.  By and large, word processing software does not.

Doing pre-press with LaTeX tends to involve post-processing the PS output with software like [psutils](http://www.tardis.ed.ac.uk/~ajcd/psutils/) or rendering to PDF and taking the pre-press workflow from there.  Generally, most pre-press houses can work from PDF, so a good PDF writing tool like Distiller is the best interface for work prepared from tools that are not designed for prepress work.  Note that the quality of the output from [Distiller](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/) tends to be better than the [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) based ones like [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/).

Note that the RGB colour space of a monitor does not have a direct map to a CYMK colour space used by a printing press.  Actually getting colours - especially colour photos - to come out correctly on a press is somewhat fraught if you do not have the right kit.  For print production, see a specialist unless you have reason to believe you know what you're doing.  For a casual user I would still recommend this 15 years after I was involved in the industry, as mistakes are ***very*** expensive to fix once they're committed to print.

If you really do want to do colour print work in-house, you will probably need to [calibrate](http://www.normankoren.com/makingfineprints1A.html) your monitor.  For best results, you should get a high-fidelity monitor like [this one](http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/default.aspx?cc=uk&oid=3648397&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_UKEN) from HP.  In order to calibrate the monitor you may also need a sensor like one of the ones described in [this review](http://www.drycreekphoto.com/Learn/monitor_calibration_tools.htm) if the monitor does not come with one.  Most professional graphics cards like these from [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/page/quadrofx_family.html), [AMD](http://ati.amd.com/products/firegl.html) or [Matrox](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/parhelia/) have facilities to support gamma correction; many consumer ones do as well.  You will also need to get calibration data for the press you are going to be using to print, although the pre-press house will probably be able to do this.

As stated before, print media is quite technical in its own right, easy to get wrong and expensive to fix once it's gone to print.  If you're not 100% certain you've got your calibration right, get a colour proof like a [Chromalin](http://www.answers.com/topic/chromalin).  This is done from the actual film separations (and is thus quite expensive), so it gives an accurate rendition of the actual colour of the final printed article.  Doing this for a few sample pages will give you accurate feedback about whether your calibration is set up right.

**Acknowledgements:** Thanks to [Aidan Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042/aidan-ryan) for expanding the section on Madcap products.

Comment: Write a book, already! ;)

Comment: Already did that (at least several large specs, white papers and assorted other documents ;-)

Comment: @Vinko, If you've used DocBook, could you expand the DocBook section a bit?

Comment: Actually it was mine; Stephan was earning his 'Strunk & White' badge by selflessly editing my dissertation ;-}

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. NXC: your answer is excellent.

Comment: Not your mistake.  I presume Peter K saw you as the last editor and assumed that you wrote the article.  I just saw a spelling mistake and edited it again a couple of days ago.  Doubtless there are one or two still left in it.

Comment: One of the best answers I have seen.

Comment: Wow, thats a nice answer!

Comment: Excellent post. I agree with everything regarding Word, FrameMaker, InDesign, and the split between technical publishing tools and page layout/design-oriented tools (InDesign, Quark, old Ventura). I've used many publishing programs, Help-system authoring tools (QuickHelp, RoboHelp, etc.), and built many small and large documents for full-color print production. I would not want to use anything but FrameMaker for technical books. I use Word for some user manuals, but it's a pain. Single-sourcing is still problematic, and I haven't gone full FrameMaker for print/PDF/online Help.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend "[Help & Manual](http://www.helpandmanual.com/)" from EC Software.  You can create a printed manual, PDF, Windows help file (CHM), and HTML web based help from a single source document.

Comment: I've used it and is possible to store the manual source in XML format so they can be added to source control without much hassle.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard good things about [FrameMaker](http://www.adobe.com/products/framemaker/). I've not used it myself, but have had it recommended to me for just such an application.

Comment: I have used FrameMaker.  There's no better product for creating software manuals, but it's not for novices.

Comment: Agreed. Using FM since 1990, there is no substitute ("often imitated, never copied")

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Framemaker indeed is the classic tool for writing user manuals. I've used it for all kinds of long documents, and it works very well. Too bad that Adobe left it to rot for years, before noticing that users wouldn't switch.

MSWord took till 2003 to get the bullet/numbering bugs out, and I don't know if they finally got master document working.

LaTeX still is a reasonable alternative. The format is easy to process, and you could generate it from a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

If you want collaboration, then a language-based approach (LaTeX would be my preference although XML-based ones are also good -- Docbook being the flagship here) does make sense, especially if you are tracking files with a version control system.

Anything that does complicate things like any software with a binary or proprietary format will not help you here.

Sorry if it is not the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ollivier that using DocBook (or LaTEX) is the sanest approach to have easy conversion, sane formatting, nice version control.

Happily, you can try to have your cake and eat it too with a DocBook editor.

Try the ones on [this list](http://wiki.docbook.org/topic/DocBookAuthoringTools) and see if any satisfies your needs (I haven't used any).

Answer (score 1):

We are using "Help & Manual" from [EC Software](http://www.ec-software.com/) and it works quite well.  Our authors are spread through the U.S. so we share our content files via a hosted SVN server to manage version control.  On each workstation we use Tortoise SVN to stay in sync.  The product is extremely easy to use and productive.

Answer (score 1):

A VERY nice explanation on what O'Reilly (actually the ones selling all these books...) uses:

[O'Reilly Toolchain](http://www.apeth.net/matt/iosbooktoolchain.html)

It may seem complicated, but depending on the amount of pages you are going to write you maybe should put some consideration into it.

Answer (score 0):

Word (or your favorite word processor)

I make all my user manuals (not to be confused with user HELP files) in Word. Then I can determine if they need to be in PDF, RTF, DOC or even converted to HTML.  To solve the multi-user updating issue, I store the file in Source Control which handles all those fun things.

Comment: We used Word and SourceSafe for our documentation on the last project I worked on.  We had to keep each section in a separate file, because the manuals were so long.  We used Adobe Acrobat to convert all the Word docs to pdf, then merged the pdf files into one pdf per manual.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Fastware Project](http://fastwareproject.blogspot.com/) blog for an in depth discussion of the tradeoffs of using DocBook etc.  Scott Meyer has tried out a lot of possibilities and shares what he's thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe InDesign CS5.5 is much better at cross references and long documents than earlier versions. It is very powerful and relatively easy to learn and use. The feature set is very rich and the more you learn about it the more you can do with it. It supports very powerful XML features and can import and export XML as needed. It can also map Styles to Tags and Tags to styles allowing you to create your XML in an automated fashion if you simply use a full set of character and paragraph styles. I have used the program for years and produced multiple projects from books to one-off advertisements. It is a graphic design tool, but has support for many aspects of book and manual production. I recommend it if you are more concerned with graphics, images or illustrations. InDesign support a wide number of import and export formats.

InDesign CS5.5 has added and improved support for both interactive content and export for EPUB (electronic book) and Adobe's Digital Publishing Suite (DPS) electronic magazine formats.

Framemaker is an excellent tool for books, manuals and long technical documents. It is a bit harder to learn than InDesign but has a richer set of tools for building variables and running headers and footers, if you have the time and inclination to learn how to use them. It also has a very robust XML feature-set, but I have not used it personally.

Unfortunately, Framemaker suffers from lack of support for graphic design. The color system is based very kludgey and spot (PMS) colors are hard to define. Simple things like adding a stroke color and fill color are rudimentary at best. For example, you still can't select a stroke color that's different from an objects fill color. The program is intended to output to laser and inkjet printers and not really to printing presses.

One feature that is really cool is the ability to apply master pages based on the Paragraph styles appearing on the page. The paragraph/illustration numbering in Framemaker is superior to any other program that I have ever used. But it is also difficult to learn and use.

Both programs support output to PDF and PostScript file formats and can generate hyperlinks and interactive content.